# decimal.TryParse returns false

Tags: c#, decimal, currency, cultureinfo

The input string in textbox is, say, $10.00 . I call

```
decimal result;
var a = decimal.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, cultureInfo, out result);
```

`cultureInfo` is known (`en-US`). Why does `decimal.tryParse` returns false?

Thank you.

Comment: An external resource from MS that explains how to parse various formats including your sample. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx

Comment: "AllowCurrencySymbol" as you've written it means allow **only** a currency symbol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you've allowed the currency symbol itself, but you've omitted other properties that are required to parse it correctly (decimal point, for example.) What you really want is `NumberStyles.Currency`:

```
decimal.TryParse("$10.00", NumberStyles.Currency, cultureInfo, out result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you need to include `NumberStyles.Number` in the bitwise combination of values for the `style` argument:

```
decimal result;
var a = decimal.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, cultureInfo, out result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allow the decimal point, too:

```
decimal result;
var enUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
var a = decimal.TryParse("$10.00", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint , enUS, out result);

Console.WriteLine(enUS);
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```